# How do I create an NSString containing an NSLineSeparatorCharacter?

Tags: cocoa, nsstring

`NSString` is pretty unicode friendly. So normally when I want to create a string containing unicode, I can pop it directly into a string literal like so:

```
NSString *myString = @"Press ⌘Q to quit…";
```

But that doesn't work with using a line separator (AKA:  `NSLineSeparatorCharacter`, Unicode U+2028, UTF-8 E2 80 A8). The compiler (correctly) interprets this as a line break, which is a no-no in C syntax.

`-stringWithFormat:` doesn't help either. Trying

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat@"This is%don two lines…", NSLineSeparatorCharacter];
```

gives me the string "This is8232on two lines…".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out `-stringWithFormat:` is the right way to go. I just need to use `%C` as the substitution instead of `%d`. `NSLineSeparatorCharacter` is an enumeration (and thus, integral), so the compiler thinks `%d` is what I should be using. But `%C` is Cocoa's way of inserting `unichar` types. With a little casting...

```
NSLog(@"This is%Con two lines…", (unichar)NSLineSeparatorCharacter);
```

Works like a charm!

Also note Ken's comment below: you can embed the character directly in a string literal using an escape sequence:

```
@"This is\u2028on two lines…"
```

Comment: You can also just embed the character using an escape sequence: `@"This is\u2028on two lines…"`